# when using contenteditable in div html it produces unwanted br though i used keydown code

Tags: javascript

I have used a code snippet

```
$('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {      
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');      
        return false;
    }
});
```

But still it doesnot work
Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match keycode do `if (e.keyCode == 13)` instead of `if (e.keyCode === 13)`

```js
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable=true>
  Enter
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it could help :)